# Dataset for emotion classification

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research, sentiment-analysis

I'm looking for a dataset for moods or emotions (Happy, Angry, Sad) classification. That's to classify the sentiment of a given text. I would like to use Naive Bayes classifier for this analysis. Not only to train and test the model with the dataset, but rather to practice doing sentiment classification. Do you suggest any resources?

Comment: We are doing a similar project to yours, we are nearing deadline. Could you please send me your datasets please. Regards

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/4052)

Comment: Related Question at stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30703485/dataset-for-emotion-detection-by-text/34860872#34860872

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some nice data sets for practicing sentiment classification are:

- [Sentiment 140](http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students/)
- [Tweets2011](http://Tweets2011)
- [Dataset by Sanders](http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/)
- [Another source](http://thinknook.com/twitter-sentiment-analysis-training-corpus-dataset-2012-09-22/)
- [This one on Github](https://github.com/guyz/twitter-sentiment-dataset)
- [One from a Kaggle contest](https://inclass.kaggle.com/c/si650winter11/data)

These are some open datasets which contain emotions like happy, sad, etc:

- [Affective Sciences](http://www.affective-sciences.org/system/files/webpage/ISEAR_0.zip)  (Data in .sav data files)

Comment: Some useful links, but be aware that the first one says it's not open.  (and it's code, not a dataset).  The second one's a broken link.  Many of the others don't explicitly list a license.  (eg, the third said 'free' but that doesn't mean it's 'open').

Comment: @Joe Thanks for pointing out.  I have used these in my projects. Some of them can be obtained by e-mailing the compilers.  But yeah, I think some aren't open here.

Comment: Actually I am looking for some text data which will contain Happy, Angry and sad related corpus not positive/ negative and not some word data

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Added another _relevant_ data source.  The data is in the form of .sav files.

Comment: Thank you :) can you give me your email or fb id to contract in future.

Comment: Good answer (+1). Could you also please edit into your answer which ones are open and which ones not?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a [good data source](http://www.saifmohammad.com/WebPages/NRC-Emotion-Lexicon.htm) and the researcher also done a work on it. refer it too.

good luck

Comment: Actually I am looking for some text data which will contain Happy, Angry and sad related corpus not positive/ negative and not some word data

Answer (score 1):

Why not you use [Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) to search your particular type text, then do some text modification. Sorry, I am not expert, it is just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

The best one I know is this:

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/

this is also available in MySQL format!

https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/jpfeiff/enron.html

It's the email corpus of Enron during the moments when it collapsed. The emails are clearly characterized by underlying feelings.

This dataset is quite unique and heavily described in the podcast Linear Digressions. It's one of a kind because after privacy laws kicked in it is not possible to ever get anything else like it again.

Happy Sciencing!